# SQL Show All column by one column distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates, distinct

I have a table with duplicate item's ...
I need show the list of all columns without duplicate item's
for example i have this table:

```
ID        CODE        RANK     TIME
1         12345        2       10:00
2         12345        2       11:00
3         98765        3       20:00
4         98765        3       22:00
5         66666        2       10:00
6         55555        5       11:00
```

result , i need :

```
ID         CODE       RANK     TIME
1         12345        2       10:00
3         98765        3       20:00
5         66666        2       10:00
6         55555        5       11:00
```

The time column in not Important , only one of them most be show ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID IN(SELECT MIN(ID) FROM myTable GROUP BY Code)
```

Comment: Actually, use MIN() as his example output takes the smallest ID. Maybe it matters.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific way the ID should show (just like the time column), and the ID and TIME column are always sorted that way,this should work.

`SELECT MIN(id), code, rank, MIN(time) 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY code, rank`

Answer (score 0):

So you only want rows where the `CODE` is not duplicated in the table.

```
SELECT "CODE"
FROM table1
GROUP BY "CODE"
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This will return the distinct `CODE`-s. Based on them - as they are unique - you can self-join it to fetch the whole rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE "CODE" IN (
    SELECT "CODE"
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY "CODE"
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for the DISTINCT clause;

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  column_1,
  column_2
FROM
  tbl_name;
```

Comment: Duplicated row is distinct from the original row (ID Column changes, also TIME), so distinct will return both rows.